# Assign JavaScript function value to a Freemarker variable

Tags: javascript, freemarker

I have a JavaScript function in my Freemarker file as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunc(){
    var myString = "I like pizza";
    return myString;
  }
</script>
```

I am trying to assign the myString return value from myFunc to myVar in Freemarker as follows:

```
<#assign myVar = myFunc()>
```

Unfortunately, the value of myVar is an ampty String ("").
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

FreeMarker runs on the web server, while the JavaScript runs in the browser later. So you should end up with an error where FreeMarker complains that there's no such thing as `myFunc`. No idea how you end up with an empty string in `myVar` instead (maybe there's some more oversight related to that), but in any case, what you trying to do won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return **myString** from **myFunc()**. Where you have defined **myString**?
Is it in a parent scope of **myFunc()**? If it is not, there are two possible scenarios!

- Scenario 1: **Non-Strict mode** - A new **myString** variable is created and will be returned, which is a possible cause for your problem of empty String!
- Scenario 2: **Strict mode** - Variable **myString** will be returned as undefined, which is not your case.

Possible Solutions - Instantiate the variable using some values in parent scope or current scope of **myFunc()**

**Edited**

I am afraid to see that **freemaker templates** would be compiled in ***server***. Alternative solution is to include the entire freemaker call-site in script tag, so that it will work based on client side instance, if you need a JavaScript in that template after compiled to scriptin client's browser.

Comment: I updated the question with a correction on where myString is defined. Thank you for your answer and pointing that out!